# AWS Elasticsearch & VPC - configuring network access from my fixed IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, kibana, amazon-vpc, amazon-elasticsearch

I am unable to access AWS Elasticsearch Kibana with a browser.

I have set up an Elasticsearch instance within my VPC exactly as described here;

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-elasticsearch-service-now-supports-vpc/

I used the default IAM access policy template which is basicaly all current IAM profiles (*)

My EC2 webapp (xenforo forum) is happily connected and chugging away.

I would like to access my elasticsearch domain kibana endpoint via browser from my home PC.

The security group I attached to the cluster configuration includes a rule to allow ALL TCP inbound from my home broadband fixed IP address.

I log into the AWS console, click the Kibana link from the elasticsearch domain overview and...   nothing, times out.

I have read everything I can find on the matter.  No joy - except perhaps I should be signing my https requests as well which seems crazy complicated and my understanding is that IP access should be configurable with security groups?

Can anyone clarify?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I have the exact same issue...

Comment: Yes & no.  Basically one has to be inside the VPC to browser access Kibana. So either connect via VPN, Setup a reverse proxy or use a Amazon Workspace (cloud desktop) attached to the security group.  

I got these solutions via AWS support.  Proxy solution detailed below is probably a pre-configured reverse proxy specifically for elasticsearch.

Comment: OK I'm going to whip up a reverse proxy, will post here when I'm done if you're interested

Comment: any idea why AWS ELB doesn't work? I tried that with TCP load balancer.

Comment: Why do AWS always make it so hard!

Answer (score 2):

to access Kibana, it seems the only way is pass proper header with your requests to.

We solved it by using https://github.com/abutaha/aws-es-proxy - its not niciest, but works for us.

- requires to have aws-cli installed
- requires to do bit of setup, but works well afterwards

hope it helps

Comment: And how do you make sure only you can access it?

Comment: Because its run locally. And its because only 2-3 ppl from our company are accessing Kibana. Its easier to set that for them (with theirs keys), then installing any other tool/server/service somewhere online. I Understand that your use-case could be different though

Answer (score 0):

Hi There are many ways to access Kibana here are some of them that I found:-

1. Use an SSH tunnel. For information on how to do this :- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/kibana-outside-vpc-ssh-elasticsearch

Advantages: Provides a secure connection over the SSH protocol. All connections use the SSH port.
Disadvantages: Requires client-side configuration and a proxy server.

2. Use an NGINX Proxy. For information on how to do this, please visit reference :- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/kibana-outside-vpc-nginx-elasticsearch

Advantages: Setup is easier, because only server-side configuration is required. Uses standard HTTP (port 80) and HTTPS (port 443).
Disadvantages: Requires a proxy server. The security level of the connection depends on how the proxy server is configured.